# How to connect 50 A 12AWG cable to a shunt resistor in PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, connector, high-current, trace, shunt

I'm designing a PCB in which the current of a BLDC motor is measured through a [PSG4NTEBL500F](https://br.mouser.com/datasheet/2/219/PSG4-1113527.pdf) shunt resistor. The DC supply of the motor is connected to the PCB through a 12AWG cable and the circuit should handle current up to 50 A.

How can I connect the 12AWG cable to the PCB? I've thought of soldering it directly to a hole, is this approach appropriate for such high current?

How should I connect the wire to the resistor? My copper weight must be 1 oz, so a simple trace would have to have an insanely high width. The resistor will be the only component on the bottom of the PCB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like the Keystone 8197-SEMS for best flexability. It and others like it are classified as screw terminals, but can be tricky to differentiate from a terminal block when searching.
[image]

Photo from Digikey

Note, they are rather heavy if this is for a tiny plane. If I were building an ESC, I would use something like Anderson PowerPole PCB mount connectors which contain less metal instead if I did not want to solder wires directly.